# How to send data to php server using NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlconnection

I need an application where i need to send data("Hello") to a server. And get a reply saying "Bye".

Please correct me if i am wrong. I would really appreciate if the question is answered.

```
NString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello=%@",_textData]; //Parameter values from user.

NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.2.208/trail/sanj.php?&data=Hello"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[theRequest addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:parameterData];

NSURLConnection *connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(!connection1)
{
    //connected

    NSLog(@"Error Connecting.");
}
```

below is the PHP server code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['data'])
{
    echo "Bye";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it do when you try it?

Comment: Did you implement the needed `NSURLConnection` delegate methods to read the response?

Comment: yes i have implemented the delegate methods also

Comment: nothing i'm getting when i try this.

Comment: means servers is returning nothing. Problem in Server side? or Client side?

Comment: I don't see where you're asking for a response from the server...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.2.208/trail/sanj.php?data=Hello"];